# Adding group policies to new AD user

Tags: powershell, winforms, if-statement

Is there a way to add group policies to a new AD user in the same script? When I add the function of creating the new user to a button it only seems to make the new user at the end of the script, when I try to add the group policy to the variable $userName it cant find the user in AD. Can I get the new user to be made before the script ends? I also have to also declare the variable again for some reason.

```
function Creation {
    
    $firstName = $textbox_FirstName.Text
    $middleName = $textbox_MiddleName.Text
    $lastName = $textbox_Surname.Text
    $jobCode = $textbox_JobCode.Text
    $Password = $textbox_Password.Text | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    
    if ($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Aberdeen") {
        $OU = "OU=Aberdeen,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
    } elseif ($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Kingpin") {
        $OU = "OU=Kingpin,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
    }
    
    if (($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Banbury") -and ($dropdown_SecondOU.Text -eq "Business Development")) {
        $OU = "OU=Business Development,OU=Banbury,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
    } elseif (($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Banbury") -and ($dropdown_SecondOU.Text -eq "CTI/Property")) {
        $OU = "OU=CTI / Property,OU=Banbury,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
    }

    if (($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "London") -and ($dropdown_SecondOU.Text -eq "Heathrow03") -and ($dropdown_ThirdOU.Text -eq "Heathrow03")) {
        $OU = "OU=Heathrow03,OU=Heathrow03,OU=London,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
    }

    $Telephone = $textbox_Telephone.Text
    
    if ($textbox_MiddleName.Text -eq "") {
        $displayName = "$lastName, $firstName"
        $userName = "$firstName.$lastName"
    } else {
        $displayName = "$lastName, $firstName $middleName"
        $userName = "$firstName.$middleName.$lastName"
    }

    New-ADUser -Name "$userName" -GivenName "$firstName" -Surname "$lastName" -Initials "$middleName" -officephone "$Telephone" -samAccountName "$userName" -AccountPassword $Password -Enabled $True -DisplayName "$displayName / Kuehne + Nagel / $jobCode" -userPrincipalName "$userName@kuehne-nagel.local" -Path "$OU"
    Set-ADUser -Identity $userName -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
}

function Template {

    $firstName = $textbox_FirstName.Text
    $middleName = $textbox_MiddleName.Text
    $lastName = $textbox_Surname.Text

    if ($textbox_MiddleName.Text -eq "") {
        $displayName = "$lastName, $firstName"
        $userName = "$firstName.$lastName"
    } else {
        $displayName = "$lastName, $firstName $middleName"
        $userName = "$firstName.$middleName.$lastName"
    }

    if ($RadioButton_IFF.Checked) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test1" -Members $UserName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the user (`New-ADUser`), you will have to retrieve the `ADUser` object in order to use it.

Example:

```
New-ADUser -Name "$userName" -GivenName "$firstName" -Surname "$lastName" -Initials "$middleName" -officephone "$Telephone" -samAccountName "$userName" -AccountPassword $Password -Enabled $True -DisplayName "$displayName / Kuehne + Nagel / $jobCode" -userPrincipalName "$userName@kuehne-nagel.local" -Path "$OU"
$UserName = Get-ADUser $userName
```

Then you can use `$userName` with the `Set-ADUser` and `Add-ADGroupMember` commands.

To be honest, it would be easier to use one function and include your condition in one.

Example:

```
function Creation {

$firstName = $textbox_FirstName.Text
$middleName = $textbox_MiddleName.Text
$lastName = $textbox_Surname.Text
$jobCode = $textbox_JobCode.Text
$Password = $textbox_Password.Text | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

if ($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Aberdeen") {
    $OU = "OU=Aberdeen,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
} elseif ($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Kingpin") {
    $OU = "OU=Kingpin,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
}

if (($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Banbury") -and ($dropdown_SecondOU.Text -eq "Business Development")) {
    $OU = "OU=Business Development,OU=Banbury,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
} elseif (($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "Banbury") -and ($dropdown_SecondOU.Text -eq "CTI/Property")) {
    $OU = "OU=CTI / Property,OU=Banbury,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
}

if (($dropdown_FirstOU.Text -eq "London") -and ($dropdown_SecondOU.Text -eq "Heathrow03") -and ($dropdown_ThirdOU.Text -eq "Heathrow03")) {
    $OU = "OU=Heathrow03,OU=Heathrow03,OU=London,OU=UK,DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local"
}

$Telephone = $textbox_Telephone.Text

if ($textbox_MiddleName.Text -eq "") {
    $displayName = "$lastName, $firstName"
    $userName = "$firstName.$lastName"
} else {
    $displayName = "$lastName, $firstName $middleName"
    $userName = "$firstName.$middleName.$lastName"
}

New-ADUser -Name "$userName" -GivenName "$firstName" -Surname "$lastName" -Initials "$middleName" -officephone "$Telephone" -samAccountName "$userName" -AccountPassword $Password -Enabled $True -DisplayName "$displayName / Kuehne + Nagel / $jobCode" -userPrincipalName "$userName@kuehne-nagel.local" -Path "$OU"
#new Part
$UserName = Get-ADUser $userName
$userName | Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True
if ($RadioButton_IFF.Checked) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test1" -Members $UserName
    }

}
```

Comment: Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Harry.Test' under: 'DC=Kuehne-Nagel,DC=local'.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\New user.ps1:58 char:9
+         Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test1" -Members $UserName

Comment: The way these functions are constructed, you will need to add it to both. Because, `$UserName`  variable will be contained within the function.  Honestly though, you should probably make this one function

Comment: I was wondering if it should be one function, let me try that but I think it will have the same error with being unable to find the user. I have tried to add a pause but that didn't help.

Comment: I updated the answer to include your function slightly modified.

Comment: You can just capture the newly created user like `$user = New-ADUser ...`. No need to use Get-ADUser afterwards.